# Where to find Kyrgyzstan trekking maps?

Tags: hiking, maps, trekking, kyrgyzstan

I'm going to Kyrgyzstan for hiking. I like wild tourism.

Where I can find **detailed maps with routes** for trekking?

Is it difficult to find such maps inside the country?

Does anyone know of links to maps with interesting routes?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the group [Community Based Tourism (CBT)](http://www.cbtkyrgyzstan.kg/en/), when I was there a few years ago they were actively exploring new trekking routes and may be able to advise of many non obvious ones. They are (or were a few years ago) also good for quality reliable homestay accommodation, safe drivers who don't take a racing line around blind corners, and guides for walking or horseback treks. They don't produce quality maps though, just [rough indications of their routes](http://www.cbtkyrgyzstan.kg/en/tours/horseback-riding-and-trekking-tours).

Comment: @user568458 why don't you make that an answer? I'd also recommend taking a look to [Caravanistan](http://caravanistan.com/kyrgyzstan/) and the attached forum.

Comment: @mts I was going to, then realised they don't do usable maps which are the one thing being asked for! I believe there are good quality (Russian language) trekking maps available in country but I don't remember where to buy them (and I think some date back to soviet times, not exactly up to date - but the mountains are still there...).

Comment: @user568458 thanks for the information. About trekking maps with russian language... It is not problem to find maps from soviet times. But they aren't modern, without routes and water points, not detailed. I had the same problem when I travelled at [Altai Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altai_Mountains). Of course I can print soviet map(as I did before), but it is not good solution. Better to have a detailed map with the sources and paths, places for camping etc. This will allow me to develop the route. And of course I like travel without guides and instructors using my own route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In popular hiking regions such as Karakol, hostels / guesthouses and outdoor equipment rentals can often provide you with suitable maps.
If there's a CBT nearby, you might be able to buy maps there - although sometimes they don't in order to promote their local hiking guides.